# How can an ISO be mounted in the terminal in the way that Ubuntu mounts an ISO by double-clicking the ISO file?

Tags: mount, iso

In Ubuntu 16.04, if I double-click on an ISO file, Ubuntu gets the volume ID, then mounts that ISO at a directory at `/media/$USER/` with the volume ID as the name of the directory. It does this without any request for root permissions.

I want to replicate this behavior in the terminal. I don't want to go first parsing the output of `isoinfo -d -i data.iso`, then granting root permissions to the user so that they then run `mkdir` in `/media/` followed by running the `mount` command etc. I want to replicate what Ubuntu is actually doing and I want to replicate it without asking the user for root permissions.

How might this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can invoke manually the [Gnome Disk Image Mounter](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/gnome-disk-image-mounter.1.html):

```
gnome-disk-image-mounter /path/to/the/iso/file.iso
```

Comment: Ah nice! This is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks. :)